# Simple function to move tokens from contract?

Tags: contract-design, tokens

I have a contract to store certain amount of tokens I created in another contract. 
I sent those tokens to the storage contract but it seems that there is no way out for that tokens, unless I construct a function.

Is there a simple function to move them out easily to any wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this into your contract, and it would allow you to send any tokens for which the contract has a balance

```
interface ERC20I {
    function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address _holder) public view returns (uint256);
}
contract Test {
    function transferTokens(address _tokenAddress, address _recipient) public onlyOwner returns (bool) { 
       ERC20I e = ERC20I(_tokenAddress);
       require(e.transfer(_recipient, e.balanceOf(this));
       return true;
   }
}
```

Note that you want to lock down this function with the use of a modifier like `onlyOwner` common to zepplin-solidity contracts, and a staple for function authorization, otherwise anyone would be able to send tokens the contract holds

Comment: Thanks @hextet Looks that a right answer to me, but I'm newbie to contract programming and 'interface' isn't a word in the syntax that the compiler understand, am I missing something very obvious or what is the error?

Comment: This RTD for Solidity covers interfaces quite well: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?highlight=interface#interfaces

Comment: Great @hextet , I added the interface and worked perfectly!

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

No.

The "storage" contract has no way to act of its own accord and there is no way to instruct it do something except to construct a function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But the storage contract is a contract also made by myself, to store those tokens until I decide to move them again to another address. I want a function to move those tokens from storage contract at a certain moment.